# compare the data passed in query string

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, query-string

sir i m working on a project and i want to pass a value in query string and redirect it to next page .....ok
now on next page i want to make a check on this 
if the value of querystring is equal to a particular value then a message show.... 
i have done upto here
now the prob comes if the values is not matched the code written in else is not working
i m writting my code:-----

```
if(request.param.count>0) then
label1.visible="true"
label1.text="hello"
else
label1.visible=false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following will test your `QueryString` to a `string` value.

```
If (Request.QueryString("MyString") == "hello") Then
    label1.Text = "Hello";
    label1.Visible = true;
Else
    label1.Visible = false;
End If
```

In your code, you had `"`'s around the `true` and `false` values.  You don't need these.